Number of solutions modulo an ideal.
Consider a number field $K$, and let us say that $O_k$ is its ring of integers. Consider an ideal $\mathfrak{b}$
I am curious about the number of solutions to the equation
$$ax \equiv 0 \mod \mathfrak{b}$$
I observed that when $\mathfrak{b}$ is a prime ideal, the number of solutions is $1$. Also when $\mathfrak{b}$ is coprime to $a$, the number of solutions is $1$. But how do I figure out the number of solutions in a general case?
Intutively it should be $\mathfrak{N}(a, \mathfrak{b})$, that is the norm of $GCD(a, \mathfrak{b})$ but I have not been able to prove this yet.
I did this for the case when $(a)$ and $\mathfrak{b}$ are coprime, and I thought I can divide both sides of equation by $GCD(a, \mathfrak{b})$ but I cannot do that since $a$ is an element of ring of integers but $GCD(a, \mathfrak{b})$ is an ideal.

From what I understand of your post, I suppose that you want the number of solutions modulo $\mathfrak{b}$ (otherwise you have infinitely many solutions, for example the elements of $\mathfrak{b}$).
Anyway, your guess is correct.
Let $R=O_K$. The image of $x\in R\mapsto ax \in R/\mathfrak{b}$ is $((a)+\mathfrak{b})/\mathfrak{b}=\Delta/ \mathfrak{b}$, where $\Delta=gcd ((a),\mathfrak{b})$.
Now the third isomorphism theorem gives an ring isomorphism $(R/\mathfrak{b})/(\Delta/ \mathfrak{b})\simeq R/\Delta$, which gives that $\Delta/\mathfrak{b}$ has cardinality $N(\mathfrak{b})N(\Delta)^{-1}$.
On the other hand, the previous map factors through a map $R/\mathfrak{b}\to R/\mathfrak{b}$, and the number of solutions you want to compute is the cardinality of its kernel. The first isomorphism theorem and the previous point yields the answer you guessed, namely $N(\Delta)=N(gcd((a),\mathfrak{b}))$.
